# How could I improve WebStorm performance on MacOS?

Tags: frontend, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm using WebStorm on MacOS Mojave. However my laptop usually spends twice or even more time than my colleague's laptop when exactly the same project is compiled. I try to modify WebStorm's VM options like enable bigger memory size.

```
# custom WebStorm VM options

-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
```

Unfortunately it doesn't have an outstanding effect.

How could I improve WebStorm performance on MacOS?

Comment: Webstorm doesn't do the compilation itself, but rather use some extra libraries. Please specify what exactly are you compiling.

Also Webstorm is built on layers/plugins. One way of improving the performance is to disable not used plugins to save some memory and computing power.

Comment: @ŁukaszOstrowski it is a Vue.js project and I use npm command to compile

Comment: Well, first you should try to run command directly in terminal -> `npm run build` or `npm run start`. But compilation time is depending on machine's speed and free resources. Do you compare the same machines?

Comment: @ŁukaszOstrowski it is still slow when I run script directly. My laptop is Mac Pro 2016 8g i5 256g and they use window on Lenovo 2014. There should be no such big difference between our machines.

Comment: Well, so now you know thats not Webstorm.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you aren't indexing your dist or www folders.

Right click the folder -> "Mark Directory As" -> "Excluded".